# Svelte set bind:value from #each Key

Tags: javascript, binding, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to bind values to a Each Value:

For example:

JS:

```
let test = ""
let headers = [
    {
      title: "test",
      connected: test,
    }
]

const setPage = () => {
    console.log(test);
  };
```

HTML:

```
{#each headers as header}
<input
 type="text"
 placeholder={header.title}
 bind:value={header.connected}
 on:change={() => setPage(1)}
/>
{/each}
```

The Header Title works as expected but the binding does not work. Is there any way that i can use it like this?

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning the start value will be set to the value of `test` - since it's an empty string in your case, that can't be seen.

After the value of the input is changed the reactive log shows that the value of `header.connected` changes accordingly.
So the binding basically does work. Not sure if you expected test to change as well? How should everything then behave if there was more than one `header` object?

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7292023aac55470c942e93c85160d028?version=3.47.0)

```
<script>
    let test = ""
    let headers = [
        {
            title: "header1",
            connected: test,
        },
        {
            title: "header2",
            connected: test,
        }
    ]

    function updateTest(event) {
        test = event.target.value
    }

    $: console.log('headers', headers)
</script>

<p>
    test: {test}
</p>

{#each headers as header}
<input
             type="text"
             placeholder={header.title}
             bind:value={header.connected}
             on:input={updateTest}
             />
{/each}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Corrl. The Headers should create searchable table header where the binding value of test is the search term. If its empty its SELECT * and when i type into the input field (will be on:change as well) new data with search term WHERE Col = test will be fetched. So its relative importent that the value test can be empty at beginning

Comment: @visual2k there's no problem with test being an empty string at the beginning. I just put a value inside, so it can be seen in the input field. Not sure I understand what you want exactly - `test` should be updated when the input value changes? And if there were more than one header inputs, `test` should be set to the last modified value?

Comment: i edited my first post. I got an on:change event, so when i typed something into the inputfield and trigger the on:change, the setPage fires as expected but the console.log shows that the value test is just empty

Comment: As @Corrl pointed out, the values are bound to `headers[].connected`. `test` is only used to *initialize* `headers[].connected`, but is not used afterwards and isn't bound to anything, so it should never update. Corrl asked you if you wanted `test` to hold the value of the most recently changed input (which can be done), but you did not answer him...

Comment: @visual2k *"the console.log shows that the value test is just empty"* - that is because there is currently no "backward connection" between the input value and `test`. The start value of the input is set based on `test`, but the binding is to `header.connected`. When the input value is changed, this `connected: test` is "replaced" by `connected: "changedInputValue"`. I modified my answer with the functionality that `test` gets set based on the last changed input value - that's what you want?

Comment: Thanks @Corrl that is kind what i was looking for. In your updated example header1 is connected to test, that is correct. But header2 should be connect to test2, header3 to test3 and so on, and all values should be stored in the variables to use them later in a fetch

Comment: @visual2k what's the reason for the seperate variables? Can't you use the `header. connected` values for the fetch instead?

Comment: @Corrl the reason is, every input field is a Search box for the Query. The user can search for the Description, but also in the description for some IDs or whatever, that's why i need that separated. If i Enter somethin in the Description field it works, but when i also lookup for an ID it only looks for the ID. So i need all values. The alternative is to bind each Input field to some variable, but that is what i wanna dodge

Comment: @visual2k While a minimal reproducible example is alway best, I think in your case your question is too simple and not showing all the logic which is hard to get by just describing. You might consider adding this *'search for the Description, but also in the description for some IDs'* logic to your code